# Rewriting the URL in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I am not sure if this is technically possible, but if I have set up HAProxy so that an incoming request to `http://example.com/hello` goes to `http://10.0.0.2/hello`:

`server example-1 10.0.0.2 check verify none`

Is it possible to do it so that `http://example.com/hello` goes to `http://10.0.0.2/greeting` instead?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784517/haproxy-route-and-rewrite-based-on-uri-path) not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This can done using "reqrep" option .

In backend , add the following the line

reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ )/hello(.*)    \1/greeting\2

The expression converts ur http://10.0.0.2/hello to http://10.0.0.2/greeting .