# Haproxy Redirect Map file can use regex?

Tags: regex, haproxy

I am using HA-Proxy version 1.5.11 2015/01/31

In my config i have a line that looks like:

```
http-request redirect location %[capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 301 if { capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found } { hdr$ { hdr(host) -i mysite.com }
```

the redirects.map file looks something like:

```
/oldurl/ /newurl/
```

Is there anyway to do regular expressions in this map file? something like:

```
/(en|sp)/oldurl/ /1/newurl/
```

The redirect map does work on a 1to1 bases and does work now. Just trying to add regular expressions to the matches to cut down on the size of the map file.

Comment: [Have a look at this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784517/haproxy-route-and-rewrite-based-on-uri-path). It might be helpful.

Comment: I understand you can do reqrep, but that is in the haproxy config file. I am adding map files to my config as i have over a million redirects. I do not want them all in my haproxy config taking up space when I can create map files for each of my domains.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this issue?